# Issues with having clone input box and to display in cart meta woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, input, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Been banging my head for weeks to solve this. Im abit novice programmer and trying to figure this out. So I would like to have cloned input box which is triggered by clicking on the .Plus button for adding quantity in product page for woocommerce.

**The cloned input box is triggered by using jQuery code below.**

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        var i=1;
        var j=2;

    $(document).on( "click", ".plus", function(){

        console.log('plus:change');    
                        $(".minus").prop('disabled', false);    
  $(".custom-text").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i},
            'placeholder':function(_, placeholder) {return placeholder + " "+ j},
      'value': ''               
    });
          }).insertAfter(".custom-text");           
  i++;  
    });
    
    $(document).on( "click", ".minus", function(){
        console.log('minus:change');       
if ($(".wccpf-field").length > 1) {    
      $(".wccpf-field:last").remove();
            j--;
            i--;
         }
      else {
                $(".minus").prop('disabled', true);
       i=1;
             j=2;
                console.log(i,j);
      }   
        });                     
            })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**PHP code**

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_fields_before_add_to_cart' );

function add_fields_before_add_to_cart( ) {
    ?>
    <table class="custom-text">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php _e( "Custom Quote:", "aoim"); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type = "text" name = "custom_quote" id = "custom_quote" placeholder = "Custom Quote">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Add data to cart item
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 25, 2 );

function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {

if ( isset( $_POST ['custom_quote'+$i] ) ) {
        $custom_data  = array() ;
      for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
        $custom_data [ 'custom_quote' ]    = isset( $_POST ['custom_quote'+$i] ) ?  sanitize_text_field ( $_POST ['custom_quote'+$i] ) : "" ;
        $cart_item_meta ['custom_data']     = $custom_data ;
      }

    return $cart_item_meta;

}
/**
 * Display custom data on cart and checkout page.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'get_item_data' , 25, 2 );

function get_item_data ( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item [ 'custom_data' ] ) ) { 
    
        $custom_data  = $cart_item [ 'custom_data' ];
          for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){      
        $other_data[] = array( 'name' => 'Custom Quote 1',
                    'display'  => $custom_data['custom_quote'+$i] );

    }
    }                                         
    return $other_data;
                              }
```

I am able to clone the input and even attach unique id,name for each cloned input box. However, I am having issue to display them in cart page.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Managed to resolve by myself. Here is the complete code. Not the most clean code but it works for me.

**PHP CODE**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_fields_before_add_to_cart' );

function add_fields_before_add_to_cart( ) {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    ?>
    <table class="custom-text">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php _e( '<b>'."Custom Quote".'</b>', "aoim"); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type = "text" class="td-width-input" name ="custom_quote" id = "custom_quote" placeholder ="Custom Quote" maxlength="100">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="custom-width">
        
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="custom-text-output">  </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <div class="msg-custom-text-standard">
        Ready-stock quote will be randomly selected by company
       </div>
       <div class="msg-custom-text-customized-quote">
         *Requires 7 working days to prepare the customised quote.<br>
       </div>
    <?php
        }
}

/**
 * Add data to cart item
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 25, 2 );

function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
     $qty=$_POST['quantity'];
    if ( isset( $_POST ['custom_quote'.$i] ) ) {

    $custom_data  = array() ;
$custom_data [ 'custom_quote' ]    = isset( $_POST ['custom_quote'] ) ?  sanitize_text_field ( $_POST ['custom_quote'] ) : "" ;
    for ($i = 1;  $i <  $qty ; ++$i){
        $custom_data [ 'custom_quote'.$i ]    = isset( $_POST ['custom_quote'.$i] ) ?  sanitize_text_field ( $_POST ['custom_quote'.$i] ) : "" ;
}
        $cart_item_meta ['custom_data']     = $custom_data ; 

    return $cart_item_meta;   
}
}

/**
 * Display custom data on cart and checkout page.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'get_item_data' , 25, 2 );

function get_item_data ( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item [ 'custom_data' ] ) ) { 
    
        $custom_data  = $cart_item [ 'custom_data' ]; 
         foreach ($custom_data as $key => $value){
             $i++;
        $other_data[] = array( 'name' => 'Custom Quote ' . $i ,
        'display'  => $value );
         }
        
    }                                 
    return $other_data;
                              }                               
    
// }
    
/**
 * Add order item meta.
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_order_item_meta' , 10, 2);

function add_order_item_meta ( $item_id, $values ) {

    if ( isset( $values [ 'custom_data' ] ) ) {

        $custom_data  = $values [ 'custom_data' ];
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Custom Quote 1', $custom_data['custom_quote'] );
            $k=1;
         foreach ($custom_data as $key => $value){
             $i++;
             $k++;
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Custom Quote '.$k, $custom_data['custom_quote'.$i] );
         }
    }
}

    // validate when add to cart
    function validation_custom_quote($passed, $product_id){
        

     $qty=$_POST['quantity'];
     $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if (isset($_POST ['custom_quote'] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST ['custom_quote'] ) == '' ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Please make sure custom quote is filled for product %s' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
        return false;       
        }
            for ($i = 1;  $i < $qty ; $i++){
        if(isset($_POST ['custom_quote'.$i] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST ['custom_quote'.$i] ) == '')  {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Please make sure all custom quotes are filled for product %s' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
        return false;

 } }
        return $passed;

     } 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validation_custom_quote', 10, 3 );
```

**JQuery CODE**

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        
        var i=1;
        var j=2;

    $(document).on( "click", ".plus", function(){

   $(".custom-text").clone().find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
        'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
        'name': function(_, name) { return name + i},
                'placeholder':function(_, placeholder) {return placeholder + " "+ j},
        'value': ''               
        });
         }).appendTo(".custom-text-output");
        i++;
        j++;
    
        console.log('plus:change');

                        $(".minus").prop('disabled', false);

    });

    $(document).on( "click", ".minus", function(){
                if(i==1){
        alert("Minimum Quantity is 1");
          return false;
       }  
        else  {   
                i--;
                j--;
            $("#custom_quote" + i).remove();
        }
        });
    $(document).on( "ready", function(){
            $('.custom-text').hide();


});

    $(document).on( "change", "#pa_bottle-quotes", function(){
        if ( this.value == 'customized-quote')
      {
        $(".custom-text").fadeIn(500).show();
                $(".custom-text-output").fadeIn(500).show();
                $(".msg-custom-text-standard").hide();
                $(".msg-custom-text-customized-quote").fadeIn(500).show();
                
      }
      else if( this.value == 'standard-quote')
      {         
        $(".custom-text").hide();
                $(".custom-text-output").hide();
                $(".msg-custom-text-standard").fadeIn(500).show();
                $(".msg-custom-text-customized-quote").hide();

      }
            else {
        $(".custom-text").hide();
                $(".custom-text-output").hide();
                $(".msg-custom-text-standard").hide();
                $(".msg-custom-text-customized-quote").hide();

            }
 
    });

$(document).on( "ready", function(){
            $(".custom-text").hide();
                $(".custom-text-output").hide();
                $(".msg-custom-text-standard").hide();
                $(".msg-custom-text-customized-quote").hide();
        });
$(document).on("click",".single_add_to_cart_button", function() {

        if ( $("#pa_bottle-quotes option:selected").text() == 'Standard Quote') {
                        $(".custom-text").remove();
                        $(".custom-text-output").remove();          
            }
        else {
            console.log("customized");
        }               
});     
            })(jQuery);
</script>
```